# Objects falling on Slopes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, kinematics

An object falls on a slope and then rebounces....and it is known it hits the slope again...how do I calculate it's second point of contact with the slope....how can a projectory equation be used in this case?

Answer (score 0):

After the object first falls onto the slope it will suffer a collision applying the equations for collision you can calculate the speed and direction of velocity from the first point of calculation. Now you can break down the velocity into two components I.e. one along the slope and one perlendiculat to the slope. Now you must calculate the force of gravity and break it into components as well. The one perpendicular to slope can be used to find when it will return to slope again I.e. time of flight and one parallel to slope can be used to determined what will be the distance from thr first point.

Note : your question does not satisfy the sites terms and condition as you only want to know how to reach your answer. In case your question was that how was the projectory equations valid in this case , i  would ask you to give a proper reason for why they should not be applicable.